# How can I get all files that fit a search pattern?

Tags: c#, regex, file, search, directory

I'm trying to get all files that fit a specific pattern. The file names are comprised of 3 elements which I will refer to as x, y, and z (all are numbers).

- X is generally 5 digits long.
- Y is generally 1 digit long.
- Z can be up to 2 digits long.

For this example, x = 65986 and y = 1.

I want to get all the files that fit this pattern: `65986_1_Z.csv` where Z can be any digit between 1 and 100 (exclusive).

This is what I currently have:

```cs
FileInfo[] files = di.GetFiles(x + '_' + y + "_*.csv");
```

This somewhat works in that I can get all the files from `65986_1_1.csv` to `65986_1_9.csv`, but once that final value becomes 10 or greater, this search pattern does not return those files where z > 10.

Am I misusing the '*' wildcard or is there something else I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Frankly, this looks like a framework bug.  Instead of doing this, use Linq on the entire list of files to obtain the subset you want.  You can String.Split() the file name using an underscore as a delimiter to get Z.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using the [RegEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=netframework-4.8) is accepted, then please consider the following:

```cs
var dir = @"YourDir";
var pat = @"(\d{5}_)(\d{1}_)(\d{1,3}).csv$";
var q = from f in Directory.EnumerateFiles(dir, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        where Regex.IsMatch(f, pat)
        select f;
q.ToList().ForEach(f => Console.WriteLine(f));
```

You can evaluate the RegEx pattern [here](https://regex101.com/r/Ou5ruY/5).

Good Luck.

Comment: Most Welcome. Good Luck.